# A watchdog type program needed

Tags: java

I need to make a watchdog type program, for example in an execution process my control goes in any method-

```
------some line--------
boolean b = goInThisBlock();
--------Some line---------
```

in some rare cases the control goes into it and takes a long time to come out. So I want to avoid those cases by watchdog type check. When control goes into the method, start the count and if wait time is more than 2 mins get out of that, meaning jump to next line of process.

So how could I achieve this in java.

Comment: Don't really get it. Maybe you would want to run functions in a separated thread?

Comment: @AlvinWong yes it could be a solution but any other thing that i can do here.

Comment: Threads. Simple as that.

Comment: Basically you want to profile the execution of this function

Comment: @UmNyobe yes it is profiling type work. could you answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to profile your application. Run a profiler on the entire program, then you can see the amount of "runtime" taken by the function you care about (`goInThisBlock` need to be a function). Most of the time you have to possibility to zoom in and see at the scope of `goInThisBlock`.

Rather than using a timer to see if the function spends more than 2 mins, you will have the opportunity to know ***why and when*** the function spends more than 2 mins. Then it is your call to find an appropriate solution.

You can use [any profiler in this list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14808/1122645) to achieve that.